# How to retrieve quantity input field by id in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to retrieve quantity input field for the product having 95 id. trying this function but it is not
working. it adds only one product in cart even after selecting more than one in the input field.

```
<div class="quantity">
<label>QTY</label>
<?php woocommerce_quantity_input(array(
'id'=>95
)); ?>  
</div>
```

Comment: That's not how you specify the current product for woocommerce_quantity_input, no. Which documentation are you following for that function? From the source code it looks like you'll need to pass the product object as the second argument, or have product 95 be the global product at that point.

Comment: what will be $product = ? in second argument?